# Powershell Format-Wide and Sorting

Tags: sorting, powershell, get-childitem

One of the things I like to do in Powershell is:

```
Set-Location 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\en-US\'
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Format-Wide -Column 3
```

This gives me a great view on everything there is to learn and explore. The thing that bothered me is the sorting, because now I have 3 columns that start with 'A'. It would be more readable when I'd have (for example) one column with A-J, one column L-R, and one going from R-Z. This bothered me so much, I wrote a function to do it:

```
Function PSHELP {    
    Set-Location 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\en-US\'

    #Initialize variables
    $files = gci *.txt | select name
    $count = $files.count
    $remainder = $count % 3
    $rows = ($count - $remainder) /3 -as [int]

    #I add an extra row by default, to deal with remainders
    $rows++
    $Table = New-Object 'object[,]' $rows,3


    #Build up a table the way I want to see it
    #column 1: A,B,C...
    #column 2: L,M,N..
    #column 3: R,...,Z

    $index = 0
    for ($j = 0; $j -lt 3; $j++)
    {   
        $ThisColumnLength = $rows
        if($j -ge $remainder){
            $ThisColumnLength--
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i -lt $ThisColumnLength; $i++)
        { 
            $table[$i,$j] = $files[$index]
            $index++
        }        
    }

    #Read the table in the order Format-Wide throws them on the screen
    #And store this in an array
    $array = @()
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $rows; $i++)
    {   $ThisRowLength = 3

        if(($i+1) -eq $Rows){
            $ThisRowLength = $remainder
        }

        if ($ThisRowLength -gt 0){
            for ($j = 0; $j -lt $ThisRowLength; $j++)
            { 
                $array += $table[$i,$j]
            }
        }
    }

    $array | fw -Column 3
}
```

Is there a more 'standard' way to do this in powershell? It seems like quite a natural option to me, but I couldn't find it. Is there an option or command that I've missed?

To clarify: I am not looking for ways to find help. This question is about the Format-Wide command, and/or possible alternative. I just thought this would be a nice example.

[Edit:] Changed my function to something slightly less clumbsy.

[Edit2:] The code I posted is flawed, and it's getting late. If you paste it in the shell and compare it with {Get-Childitem *.txt | format-wide -column 3}', you should be able to see what I am trying to do here. I hope somebody can suggest some kind of alternative.

[Edit3:] Modified the code again, finally got this to work. In the process I found out a very interesting thing about what Format-Wide returns:

PS> (Get-ChildItem).count
Result: 125

PS> (Get-ChildItem | Format-Wide).count
Result: 129

This confused me a lot, because sometimes I counted the results and didn't get what I expected, so a couple of times I thought something was wrong with my code, but maybe everything was fine.

Answer (score 1):

I found something that does exactly what I want, and is more generic:
<strike>http://www.leporelo.eu/blog.aspx?id=powershell-formatting-format-wide-rotated-to-format-columns</strike> (dead link)

- [Version 0.4 code](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Posh-IBWAPI/1.4/Content/Private%5CFormat-Columns.ps1) (pasted at the bottom of this answer in case this link dies too)
- [Archived 0.1 code](https://web.archive.org/web/20160825112212/http://www.leporelo.eu/blog.aspx?id=powershell-formatting-format-wide-rotated-to-format-columns) (included because it has more discussion/examples)

Example with regular Format-Wide

```
'The basic promise behind implicit remoting is that you can work ' +
'with remote commands using local syntax.' -split ' ' | Format-Wide -force -prop {$_} -col 3
  
  The                        basic                      promise
  behind                     implicit                   remoting
  is                         that                       you
  can                        work                       with
  remote                     commands                   using
  local                      syntax.
```

Example with Format-Columns

```
'The basic promise behind implicit remoting is that you can work ' +
'with remote commands using local syntax.' -split ' ' | . Format-Columns -col 3
  
  The                       is                        remote
  basic                     that                      commands
  promise                   you                       using
  behind                    can                       local
  implicit                  work                      syntax.
  remoting                  with
```

I am still surprised Powershell doesn't have a built-in option to do this.

Version 0.4 code:

```
function Format-Columns {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [PsObject[]]$InputObject,
        [Object]$Property,
        [int]$Column,
        [int]$MaxColumn,
        [switch]$Autosize
    )
    
    Begin   { $values = @() }
    Process { $values += $InputObject }
    End {
        function ProcessValues {
            $ret = $values
            $p = $Property
            if ($p -is [Hashtable]) {
                $exp = $p.Expression
                if ($exp) {
                    if ($exp -is [string])          { $ret = $ret | % { $_.($exp) } }
                    elseif ($exp -is [scriptblock]) { $ret = $ret | % { & $exp $_} }
                    else                            { throw 'Invalid Expression value' }
                }
                if ($p.FormatString) {
                    if ($p.FormatString -is [string]) {    $ret = $ret | % { $p.FormatString -f $_ } }
                    else {                              throw 'Invalid format string' }
                }
            }
            elseif ($p -is [scriptblock]) { $ret = $ret | % { & $p $_} }
            elseif ($p -is [string]) {      $ret = $ret | % { $_.$p } }
            elseif ($p -ne $null) {         throw 'Invalid -property type' }
            # in case there were some numbers, objects, etc., convert them to string
            $ret | % { $_.ToString() }
        }
        if (!$Column) { $Autosize = $true }
        $values = ProcessValues

        $valuesCount = @($values).Count
        if ($valuesCount -eq 1) {
            return $values
        }
        
        # from some reason the console host doesn't use the last column and writes to new line
        $consoleWidth          = $host.ui.RawUI.maxWindowSize.Width - 1
        $gutterWidth = 2

        # get length of the longest string
        $values | % -Begin { [int]$maxLength = -1 } -Process { $maxLength = [Math]::Max($maxLength,$_.Length) }

        # get count of columns if not provided
        if ($Autosize) {
            $Column         = [Math]::Max( 1, ([Math]::Floor(($consoleWidth/($maxLength+$gutterWidth)))) )
            $remainingSpace = $consoleWidth - $Column*($maxLength+$gutterWidth);
            if ($remainingSpace -ge $maxLength) { 
                $Column++ 
            }
            if ($MaxColumn -and $MaxColumn -lt $Column) {
                $Column = $MaxColumn
            }
        }
        $countOfRows       = [Math]::Ceiling($valuesCount / $Column)
        $maxPossibleLength = [Math]::Floor( ($consoleWidth / $Column) )

        # cut too long values, considers count of columns and space between them
        $values = $values | % {
            if ($_.length -gt $maxPossibleLength) { $_.Remove($maxPossibleLength-2) + '..' }
            else { $_ }
        }

        #add empty values so that the values fill rectangle (2 dim array) without space
        if ($Column -gt 1) {
            $values += (@('') * ($countOfRows*$Column - $valuesCount))
        }
        # in case there is only one item, make it array
        $values = @($values)
        <#
        now we have values like this: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ''
        and we want to display them like this:
        1 3 5 7
        2 4 6 ''
        #>
        
        $formatString = (1..$Column | %{ "{$($_-1),-$maxPossibleLength}" }) -join ''

        1..$countOfRows | % {
            $r    = $_-1
            $line = @(1..$Column | %{ $values[$r + ($_-1)*$countOfRows]} )
            Write-Output "$($formatString -f $line)".PadRight($consoleWidth,' ')
        }
    }

    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
        Formats incoming data to columns.
    .DESCRIPTION
        It works similarly as Format-Wide but it works vertically. Format-Wide outputs the data row by row, but Format-Columns outputs them column by column.
    .PARAMETER Property
        Name of property to get from the object.
        It may be
            -- string - name of property.
            -- scriptblock
            -- hashtable with keys 'Expression' (value is string=property name or scriptblock)
                and 'FormatString' (used in -f operator)
    .PARAMETER Column
        Count of columns
    .PARAMETER Autosize
        Determines if count of columns is computed automatically.
    .PARAMETER MaxColumn
        Maximal count of columns if Autosize is specified
    .PARAMETER InputObject
        Data to display
    .EXAMPLE
        1..150 | Format-Columns -Autosize
    .EXAMPLE
        Format-Columns -Col 3 -Input 1..130
    .EXAMPLE
        Get-Process | Format-Columns -prop @{Expression='Handles'; FormatString='{0:00000}'} -auto
    .EXAMPLE
        Get-Process | Format-Columns -prop {$_.Handles} -auto
    .NOTES
        Name: Get-Columns
        Author: stej, http://twitter.com/stejcz
        Site: http://www.leporelo.eu/blog.aspx?id=powershell-formatting-format-wide-rotated-to-format-columns
        Lastedit: 2017-09-11
        Version 0.4 - 2017-09-11
        - removed color support and changed output from Write-Host to Write-Output
        Version 0.3 - 2017-04-24
        - added ForegroundColor and BackgroundColor
        Version 0.2 - 2010-01-14
        - added MaxColumn
        - fixed bug - displaying collection of 1 item was incorrect
        Version 0.1 - 2010-01-06
    #>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean standard way of finding all the help files in PowerShell, then yes there:

```
Get-Help * -Category HelpFile
```

Outside of that I just go check this page on Technet: [Windows PowerShell Core About Topics](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847856.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fork of the above script in a module form: https://github.com/loxia01/FormatColumn

Function syntax:

```
Format-Column [[-Property] <Object>] [-MaxColumnCount <int>] [-MinRowCount <int>] [-OrderBy <string>] [-InputObject <psobject>] [<CommonParameters>]

Format-Column [[-Property] <Object>] -ColumnCount <int> [-OrderBy <string>] [-InputObject <psobject>] [<CommonParameters>]
```